# Android: Create activity on home screen with user's permission

Tags: android, android-widget, android-activity

I have created a widget and it's working properly. If the user wants, he can add my application's widget on the home screen. However, what I want is, for my own code to "put the widget on the homescreen" with user's permission; because the widget is the most important part of the application, without which it'd be useless.

I'd like to implement something like the following:

a. For example, when an application tries to start bluetooth, the system tells the user "Ok dude, this application wants to turn on bluetooth, do you want to allow this?". Similarly, "Application X is trying to create a home screen widget, do you want to allow it?".

or

b. When you try to add a widget manually to homescreen, the system shows a list of available widgets that you can choose from, and then you select the one you want. Is there some way where I can call this "list of widgets activity" from my code, when my application starts up?

Thanks for the suggestions!